# EdgeDriver fails running from Windows Command Line

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge

I am facing some problems trying to run EdgeDriver from the command line. The Driver runs well when is ran from the IDE (IntelliJ or Eclipse) and when is ran from the IntelliJ Terminal. But it doesn't navigate when I am running from the Windows command line. It just open the browser but doesn't get the web page. Any clue?